# Python basics: How to read N ints until '\n' is found in stdin

Tags: python, stdin

How can I read N `int`s from the input, and stop reading when I find `\n`? Also, how can I add them to an array that I can work with?

I'm looking for something like this from C but in python

```c
while(scanf("%d%c",&somearray[i],&c)!=EOF){
    i++;
    if (c == '\n'){
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Python 2:

```
lst = map(int, raw_input().split())
```

`raw_input()` reads a whole line from the input (stopping at the `\n`) as a string.
`.split()` creates a list of strings by splitting the input into words.
`map(int, ...)` creates integers from those words.

In Python 3 `raw_input` has been renamed to `input` and `map` returns an iterator rather than a list, so a couple of changes need to be made:

```
lst = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Answer (score 13):

There is no direct equivalent of scanf in Python, but this should work

```
somearray = map(int, raw_input().split())
```

In Python3 `raw_input` has been renamed to `input`

```
somearray = map(int, input().split())
```

Here is a breakdown/explanation

```
>>> raw=raw_input()              # raw_input waits for some input
1 2 3 4 5                        # I entered this
>>> print raw
1 2 3 4 5                            
>>> print raw.split()            # Make a list by splitting raw at whitespace
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']            
>>> print map(int, raw.split())  # map calls each int() for each item in the list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```